# angular bootstrap datetimepicker set available date

Tags: html, angularjs

I am using a angular bootstrap datetimepicker from https://github.com/dalelotts/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker.
I want to set the available select day from today and today + 7. 
In the order words, disabled all other day.
Any suggestions will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: is your problem resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the before-render callback to disable any dates that are out of range.

There is an example in the demo page.

Something like this should work (not tested at all)

```
function renderOnBeforeRender($dates) {

  var now = moment.valueOf();
  var max = moment().add('day', 7).valueOf();

  angular.forEach($dates, function (dateObject) {
    dateObject.selectable = (dateObject.localDateValue() >= now && dateObject.localDateValue() <= max)
  });
}
```